# Python: doing an action depending of the type of object

Tags: python, objects

hello i have a really simple problem

if my active object is an mesh i want to do an action, if its an empty another one, ... ect

so i want for example in this case, move the location of the active object only if it's an empty

so i tried

```
if bpy.context.object.type = 'EMPTY'
    bpy.context.object.location[0] = 8.46184
```

i really dont understand why it doesnt work, when i type

```
bpy.context.object.type
```

in blender python console, i have 'EMPTY' as an response...

what is wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to assign 'EMPTY' to "bpy.context.object.type" within an if clause.
For checking the value of something, you need to use "==", not "=".

```
if bpy.context.object.type == 'EMPTY':
    bpy.context.object.location[0] = 8.46184
```

Answer (score 4):

**These are basic syntax errors.**

The same errors will be produced by code completely void of any blender API reference,

```
if x = 3
    x = 4
```

and whether in blenders python console, or a python shell or any other python console, you can crunch it in and receive feedback on the errors, as well as variable values etc.

Here is the output of if statement in py console. The writing in **red** indicates an error.  If you are using the text editor, the error statement will be written in the error pop-up on run, and to the system console.

[image]

At this point, rather than writing a question:

Copy the error type and paste into google, or another search engine of your choosing

[image]

Similarly the first match for [python if statement syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186811/python-if-statement-syntax-error)

After checking out some answers you still don't understand, then write a question.  Post the error messages and other details.