# Error on displaying an image in UI script

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I want to make an image display in UI panel so I find this [how to display an image in blender UI with python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155135/how-to-display-an-image-in-blender-ui-with-python)
but when I run script of this which provided in [how to display an image in blender UI with python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155135/how-to-display-an-image-in-blender-ui-with-python)

```
import os
import bpy
import bpy.utils.previews

directory   = os.path.join(bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS'), "presets", "scatter_presets_custom\\")
list_raw = []

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(directory) if isfile(join(directory, f))]

for f in onlyfiles:
    if f[-4:] == ".jpg":
        list_raw.append(f)

class Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the 3D view Tools panel"""
    bl_idname = "TEST_PT_Panel" 
    bl_label = "Scatter Icon test"
    bl_category = "Scatter BETA"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def draw(self, context):
        global custom_icons

        for z in list_raw:
            self.layout.template_icon(icon_value=custom_icons[z[:-4]].icon_id,scale=10)

# global variable to store icons in
custom_icons = None

def register():
    global custom_icons
    custom_icons = bpy.utils.previews.new()

    for z in list_raw:
        custom_icons.load(z[:-4], os.path.join(directory, z), 'IMAGE')


    bpy.utils.register_class(Panel)

def unregister():
    global custom_icons
    bpy.utils.previews.remove(custom_icons)

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Panel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Blender showed this error `Python script failed, check the message in the system console`  see the photo below
[image]

[image]

So I go and check toggle system console and it showed this. I don't know what is the problem.
[image]

I have a question on [how to display an image in blender UI with python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155135/how-to-display-an-image-in-blender-ui-with-python)  Where can I paste the file location of my image? Can anyone tell me in where can I paste my file location of that photos or the script can find the path itself?
2nd question: Can I connect this script to the path which I searched in add-on preference
[image]

Comment: @8NFILMS - Should we wait for your answer?

Comment: Who is @8NFILMS?

Comment: Do you know what can I do to fix this? If you know, please help me on the script.

Comment: To assist with debugging generic python errors. Recommend searching for  _"python FIleNotFoundError"_

Comment: That's mean what code do I need to type? Where to search?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127990/15543

Comment: It shown this(a screenshot link): https://i2.paste.pics/C3YGG.png   Then, what can I do?